# What is the state of PnP various projects

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

This is not a technical question.

I was gone from Sharepoint Development for a couple of years and PnP seems a mess now. Many things we search we land on PnP various sites (Even Microsoft own documentation sometimes refers to PnP solutions) and get a feeling something is wrong/abandoned. After digging on github it says it is not maintained anymore.

Sometimes it points you to new github projects which there is little documentation, others it does not say anything.

For instance had lots of trouble recently connecting a C# application to Sharepoint using CSOM because of not up to date documentation.

Now I need to make a SPFx App and wanted to try PnP, but the generator page is old (nothing says the project has been abandoned) and github says it is not maintained anymore.

What projects of PnP are still alive?
Is it still safe to use PnP sp-dev-fx-controls-react and sp-dev-fx-property-controls, at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pnpjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) is fine. [sp-dev-fx-controls](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react) and [sp-dev-fx-property-controls](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls)  are also kind of fine. There is a [SharePoint Framework community call](https://pnp.github.io/#community) every second week on Thursdays with updates regarding the tools (today, 07.09, as well), you can join it to better understand the current state, or get answers directly from the Microsoft guys in the chat. The [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXdcwfcHGsGr78nHWLRsv1x) are also available.

Comment: That kind of sucks to have to go to videos to understand what is the state of the projects. When googling we land on this dead sites that don't usually tell they are dead. Or worst on Microsoft own documentation that recommends using a dead project.

Answer (score 0):

PnP is alive and very well!!  PnP has been renamed to "Microsoft 365 & Power Platform Community" and can be found at [aka.ms/community/home](https://aka.ms/community/home)

On that site, you will find links to the specific area that interests you, like samples for SPFx, MS Graph, Teams, Power Platform, and Viva.  Additionally, there are sections for custom list formatting, PnP Modern Search, and lots of guidance on all of the M365 Development areas.

The videos can be accessed from the site, as well as the schedule for multiple community calls per week.

The Community provides several tools to help with M365 development and administration, including PnPjs, PowerShell, Script samples, Microsoft 365 CLI, Teams Toolkit, and Viva Toolkit.

There are active Forums and Discord server links, as well as programs to help you get started in the community. ("Sharing is Caring")

Please check it all out and you will see how alive, active and vibrant the old "PnP" program is.

Good luck!
Don

Comment: Friendly reminder: "begging for votes" is against stackoverflow policy. Please remove your footer.

Comment: Removed. Sorry. I don't consider it begging. I am just reminding people that there are ways to Thank people for taking the time to answer their questions.